# Dynamic adding row table needs to change select id tags

Tags: php, javascript, drop-down-menu

```
<select id="1" onchange="change(this,'2')">
<option value=" " selected="selected"></option>
<option value="A">Option One</option>
<option value="B">Option Two</option>
<option value="C">Option Three</option>
<option value="D">Option Four</option>
</select>

<select id="2" onchange="change(this,'1')">
<option value=" " selected="selected"></option>
<option value="A">Option One</option>
<option value="B">Option Two</option>
<option value="C">Option Three</option>
<option value="D">Option Four</option>
</select>
```

Adding the select tags on my next row of table will just clone the id's, is there a way around this?

Comment: I just tried it out, and it worked fine for me... are you adding a row to only one of the dropdowns, or both?

Comment: When you say 'row,' you're referring to a new set of inputs? Your sample code just shows 2 selects, with no mention of rows. I'm a bit confused what we're working with here. Would you mind posting all the relevant code, rows and all?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your IDs are being incorrectly assigned. You can use Firebug or Chrome developer tools to see which IDs are being created on which dropdowns, and use that information to adjust your "change" function so that it can properly handle the adding of new rows.

Comment: I have looked at that and there doesnt seen to be any errors...I think there is something wrong with the ids as all ids are just copied down to the new rows. Not sure how to fix it.

Comment: I'm still confused if that link you gave is your exact code or not, but looking over the link, it might have to do with the fact that the js function that creates a new table row doesn't change the number id in the change() function call in the select element's onchange attribute. Every time you add a row, it simply duplicates the previous row exactly, including the id that's getting passed to the change() function.